# Hybris back-office using Jmeter and this ZK plugin

Tags: jmeter, sap-commerce-cloud, zk

I am trying to create a performance test script for Hybris back-office using Jmeter and this ZK plugin(I am assuming which is created using ZK AJAX framework). I am able to generate desktop Id(dtid) and component IDs. For some requests, I am getting the same response as a browser.
But for some requests, I am getting a blank response( {“rs”:[],”rid”:126} ). The script is sending the same parameters as the browser. In failed requests, some co-ordinates like parameters are sending.( data_1 = {“top”:242,”left”:0} ). Is the test failing because of this co-ordinates?
Please help me with this issue? Or Please suggest an alternative tool for testing the Hybris BackOffice?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Performance testing a ZK application is generally not easy, and test cases tend to be hard to maintain. It's best to probe the initial page rendering performance without too many interactions (and DON'T forget to send the rmDesktop commands at the end of each test, or your test case will not reflect reality).

I don't have a better/easier alternative to JMeter (similar tools capturing the network requests/responses propose the same challenges).

Besides that the mouse coordinates don't matter for an onClick event unless the server side event listener actually uses those to determine the outcome of the event. In 99.99% of the cases the server side is interested in the button-click event, not the mouse coordinate. If you're getting unexpected responses it's most likely the wrong component-UUID you're firing events to. In such cases the server simply ignores the event since it can't be dispatched to any matching component. Then if no event listener fires the response is most likely empty indicated by `{“rs”:[],”rid”:126}`.

One important thing is to [disable UUID-recycling](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips#Disabled_UUID_recycle) which will mix UUIDs at server side, likely resulting in the non-deterministic problems you encounter.